# Looping through List into Dictionary in order to tap element in appium

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I have this code: basically I'm trying to loop through this keypad dictionary and based on the passed in variable, tap the appropriate keys for the passcode.

```
| Create a new Passcode
| | [Documentation] | test
| | @{Passcode} = | Create List | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
| | Enter the passcode | ${Passcode}


| Enter the passcode
| | [arguments] |  @{Keys}
| | ${keypadDictionary} | Create Dictionary
| | ... | 0         | keypad-zero
| | ... | 1         | keypad-one
| | ... | 2         | keypad-two
| | ... | 3         | keypad-three
| | ... | 4         | keypad-four
| | ... | 5         | keypad-five
| | ... | 6         | keypad-six
| | ... | 7         | keypad-seven
| | ... | 8         | keypad-eight
| | ... | 9         | keypad-nine
| | wait for screen to contain element | ${Passcode screen}
| | :FOR | ${Key} | IN | @{Keys}
| | | Tap | ${keypadDictionary['${Key}']}
```

I"m getting this error:

```
Resolving variable '${keypadDictionary['[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4']']}' failed: SyntaxError:     
invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to 'enter the passcode' is passing the list in as an instance of the list.  You'll need to specify it with an @ to expand it

```
| | Enter the passcode | @{Passcode}
```